Error: process completed with exit code 1 - ASP.NET Core MVC Deployment in Azure
While trying to deploy an ASP.NET Core MVC application in Azure, I'm getting this error

Error: Process completed with exit code 1

Please see the screenshot for more details:

Actual task is to deploy ASP.NET Core MVC application in Azure.
Application framework is .NET 8 and while creating a web app in App Service selected .NET 8 framework version. Next connected it with github repository by choosing the CI enabled option in App Service.
Once clicked 'create' button, application started to build and deploy process. After sometime it throws an error, log is attached already.
Here is the progress error:

I need help to deploy application in Azure.

How you are deploying your app?

If possible please share your Code repo

I got the same issue when I followed your process of creating an Azure web app and connecting it to the GitHub repository by selecting the CI-enabled option.
The dotnet publish command is failing because of the output directory path is not valid.
So, I changed the dotnet publish and upload-artifact path in GitHub yml file as shown below.
- name: dotnet publish
  run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ./myapp

- name: Upload artifact for deployment job
  uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
  with:
    name: .net-app
    path: ./myapp

Below is my complete workflow file.
GitHub/Workflow file:
name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to Azure Web App - kaaspmvcapp
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
        with:
          dotnet-version: '8.x'
      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release
      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ./myapp
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ./myapp
  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write 
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: .net-app
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v2
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CLIENTID_<ClientId-key>}}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_TENANTID_<TenantId-key> }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_SUBSCRIPTIONID_<SUBSCRIPTIONID-key> }}
      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3
        with:
          app-name: 'kaaspmvcapp'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .

After changing workflow file it is successfully deployed to Azure App service.

Azure App Service Output:


Thank you. I have modified the output directory path in workflow file, build is successful but in the publish I am getting below error.

Error: AADSTS700016: Application with identifier '***' was not found in the directory 'Default Directory'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant. Trace ID: 3927b059-78cd-49a7-acfc-e8e1b2456800 Correlation ID: 2bd1430b-3be3-40be-a197-8d40c7fb5683 Timestamp: 2024-08-22 20:20:52Z

Error: Interactive authentication is needed. Please run:
az login
Error: Login failed with Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd' failed with exit code 1. Double check if the 'auth-type' is correct. Refer to https://github.com/Azure/login#readme for more information.

@Tamilarasan Jayaraman Did you copy, paste my entire yml?

@TamilarasanJayaraman In Azure login part you need define correct name of clientId, tenantId, SubscriptionId  of your GitHub secrets.

@TamilarasanJayaraman You can find Github secrets names in Settings -> Secrets and Variables -> Actions. See here.

Perfect ! It has many secret values. I have removed everything and kept only the active secrets in GitHub. Cross checked and modified the values of client/tenant/secret IDs. After that Build and Deployment was success. Thank you.
